# Is there a method to make flavored coffee without syrups?

Tags: flavor

As far as I've seen, flavored coffee is created by putting the beans in a tumbler with the desired syrup flavor.

Is there a method to create flavored coffee without using syrups or other sweeteners?

Comment: Are you talking about flavored coffee (final product) or flavored beans, or both?  It is possible to created flavored beans which will result in flavored coffee by adding oils to beans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there are several ways to make flavoured coffees without syrup or sweetener.

For example, I make vanilla coffee by mixing fresh vanilla seeds with finely ground medium-roast coffee, and seal the mixture for some time (duration depends on the weather). The result is quite nice, with a slight touch of vanilla. This is *not* a product---just for personal use and still exploring. The difference with syrup or essence or flavouring is that the touch feels lighter and more natural.

---

A basic mechanism here is to mix ground coffee with some spice, and let the mixture sleep for flavour to spread.

Another mechanism is to put some spice directly in a container with roasted beans. This seems more appropriate for spices like cinnamon (no need to extract seeds like for vanilla).

I have not tried to mix spices with *green* beans, as the roasting stage changes a lot of things, but that should be an interesting path.